# function bindParam() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sqlplus

Not sure what I am missing, and I couldn't find any answer on other forums or google. ._.
What am I suppose to add in the query?

```
$STH->bindParam(1, $name);
$STH->bindParam(2, $comment);
$STH = $db-("INSERT INTO comment ('name', 'comment') VALUES (:name, :comment)");
$STH->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sequence should be something like this :

```
$STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO comment ('name', 'comment') VALUES (:name, :comment)"); 
$STH->bindParam(':name', $name,PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$STH->bindParam(':comment', $comment,PDO::PARAM_STR); 

$STH->execute();
```

Comment: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object 
Like the same thing JW told me same error. ._.
I can't vote have to be a higher level. xD

Comment: The post isn't there in the database, so that means the query didn't work?

Comment: @user2288998 how are your variables assigned? can you show this process

Comment: the connection is initialized right ? and the params are being passed correctly?

Comment: This is my entire comment entry script

Comment: what we mean to know is : a) Connection is created  in $db variable ? and b) the values are being passed to this script or not ?

Comment: just noticed I was missing param's data type , corrected them i my script , try now

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Do I need to add the submit button to my script?
Make a class for this
<input type="submit" name="post">

Comment: The HTML?

<form action="comment.php" method="post" >
Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
Comment<textarea name="comment"> </textarea> <br>
<input type="submit" name="post">

Comment: I do not think so, what I seriously doubt is , your connection is being created and is being stored correctly in the variable $db or not? could you please check that

Comment: It is.
Same connection info works in the old mysql_connect scripts. Perhaps my host is being weird?

Comment: $db = new PDO(censored);
This is basically my connection.. Except with all the info in it.

Comment: you need to check if PDO is enabled on your host or not

Comment: I will contact my host about this.
THanks for your time. /upvoted as your script works locally